# Migrate Azure Synapse to GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-synapse

I have no experience on Azure cloud, and we have recently received a business requirement where data needs to be migrated from Azure synapse to Bigquery. Is there any tutorial that sheds light on how to do this? Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: BY migrated, do you want to move the data from synapse to big query on schedules basis?

Comment: Hi Nandan, 
I think it has to be both - scheduled & one time load. We'll do one time load of the history data once, but we'll still have to understand how to do a scheduled migration until we can phase out Azure completely.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Azure Data factory and Synapse pipelines do not support big query as a sink.
So you would have to write your own custom logic to move the data.

The below blog explains to move from ADLS to Big query via databricks:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reading-from-azure-datalake-writing-google-bigquery-via-deepak-rajak

So you can move the data into ADLS from synapse and then use this logic to move into destination.

Else you can modify to directly access Synapse as source.

Comment: Thanks Nandan! this is a great direction to look at, I'm definitely going to talk about with my customer's tech team.

Comment: Hi Nandan, unfortunately I'm new here and it doesn't let me upvote your answer!

Comment: I upvoted for you @dips . Another direction you can look at and do more research if GCP offers any services to migrate data into Bigquery from something like ADLS or directly from Synapse. Or maybe something like Composer has a source connector for Azure ?

Comment: Hi Ziya, Firstly thank you for upvoting for me! And yeah let me check on the directions you have mentioned.